# How to load string from flat file into date in target table(Teradata) using informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, str-to-date, flatfilesource

I am trying to load string from flat file into date in target teradata table using informatica.
 But while doing that, my workflow is succeeding but data is not loading into table.  When I run the debugger, data is passing through, SQ, expression.  When I debug the target instance, getting 'no data available' for date field.

Could any one of you help me to know how can we load string from flat file into date in target table of teradata.

date format used: MM/DD/YYYY
Source data type is string(10) and 
target data type is date in format MM/DD/YYYY.

--
Thnx,
SP

Comment: Check the log after loading. Note, that in debugger mode, target data is usuallu discarded instead of actually sending to target.

Comment: Are you using to_date to define that the source data is a date and what each character maps to?

Answer (score 0):

while debugging add an expression and check how the string is being converted to date .